Is there any way to distinguish Rust legacy mangle name from C++ mangle name?
I want to implement a function:
bool ELF_IsRustMangleSym(const char* symName)
{
  ...
}

The input parameter is a mangle name, which may be a Rust legacy name or a C++ name.
For example,
Rust mangle name:
_ZN3std2fs8Metadata7created17h8df207f105c5d474E
C++ mangle name:
_ZN5MyMapIiRKSsEC1ESt6vectorIRKSsE

By "legacy" you mean non v0, right?

Also, which C++ ABI?

this tool https://demangler.com/ can't detect this is Rust. It decodes Rust manged name into: std::fs::Metadata::created::h8df207f105c5d474.

The last 20 bytes of any symbol mangled under Rust's legacy/non-v0 scheme will start with 17h.  That might happen to collide with a C++ name, but it may be the best heuristic you'll get.

@MarekR: That is correctly demangled.  The symbol ends with a hash.

My first idea would be to use boost::demangle to try and demangle the symbol as a C++ symbol. If that fails, I'd assume it's a Rust symbol.

From reviewing the source, it appears that symbols mangled under Rust's legacy scheme will always match the following (case-sensitive) PCRE (Regex101):
^_ZN(?:[1-9]\d*[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_$.]*)+17h[0-9a-f]{16}E$

That is:

they will always start with the literal _ZN

then they will have one or more groups, each comprising:

first, a decimal integer starting with a non-zero

then, an identifier starting with either a letter or an underscore and followed by zero or more characters that may each be any of an alphanumeric or an underscore or a dollar sign or a dot

(not in the regex) the above decimal integer represents the length of the above identifier



then they will contain the literal 17h

then they will have 16 lowercase hexits

finally they will end with the literal E


C++ uses various different mangling schemes, and I think it's possible (albeit unlikely) that a C++ symbol could meet the above criteria.  The key differentiator is likely to be the final 20 bytes, which demangle to ::h0000000000000000 or similar (a 16-hexit hash prefixed by h).
